# Busy polling std::atomic - msvc optimizes loop away - why, and how to prevent?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, atomic, stdatomic

I'm trying to implement a simple busy loop function.

This should keep polling a std::atomic variable for a maximum number of times (spinCount), and return true if the status did change (to anything other than NOT_AVAILABLE) within the given tries, or false otherwise:

```
// noinline is just to be able to inspect the resulting ASM a bit easier - in final code, this function SHOULD be inlined!
__declspec(noinline) static bool trySpinWait(std::atomic<Status>* statusPtr, const int spinCount)
{
    int iSpinCount = 0;
    while (++iSpinCount < spinCount && statusPtr->load() == Status::NOT_AVAILABLE);
    return iSpinCount == spinCount;
}
```

However, it seems that MSVC just opitmizes the loop away on Release mode for Win64. I'm pretty bad with Assembly, but doesn't look to me like it's ever even trying to read the value of statusPtr at all:

```
int iSpinCount = 0;
000000013F7E2040  xor         eax,eax  
    while (++iSpinCount < spinCount && statusPtr->load() == Status::NOT_AVAILABLE);
000000013F7E2042  inc         eax  
000000013F7E2044  cmp         eax,edx  
000000013F7E2046  jge         trySpinWait+12h (013F7E2052h)  
000000013F7E2048  mov         r8d,dword ptr [rcx]  
000000013F7E204B  test        r8d,r8d  
000000013F7E204E  je          trySpinWait+2h (013F7E2042h)  
    return iSpinCount == spinCount;
000000013F7E2050  cmp         eax,edx  
000000013F7E2052  sete        al
```

My impression was that std::atomic with std::memory_order_sequential_cst creates a compiler barrier that should prevent something like this, but seems that's not the case (or rather, my understanding was probably wrong).

What am I doing wrong here, or rather - how can I best implement that loop without having it optimized away, with least impact on overall performance?

I know I could use #pragma optimize( "", off ), but (other than in the example above), in my final code I'd very much like to have this call inlined into a larger function for performance reasons. seems that this #pragma will generally prevent inlining though.

Appreciate any thoughts!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but doesn't look to me like it's ever even trying to read the value of `statusPtr` at all

It does reload it on every iteration of the loop:

```
000000013F7E2048  mov         r8d,dword ptr [rcx] # rcx is statusPtr
```

> My impression was that `std::atomic` with `std::memory_order_sequential_cst` creates a compiler barrier that should prevent something like this,

You do not need anything more than `std::memory_order_relaxed` here because there is only one variable shared between threads (even more, this code doesn't change the value of the atomic variable). There are no reordering concerns.

In other words, this function works as expected.

You may like to use `PAUSE` instruction, see [Benefitting Power and Performance Sleep Loops](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/benefitting-power-and-performance-sleep-loops).

Comment: Thanks - this is highly interesting then. I'm using this in a context of a message bus. If I set #pragma optimize( "", off ) on the above function only, everything works as expected; if I don't, it bugs out though (messages arriving out of order or with wrong - possibly outdated - data). Seems almost too weird to be coincidence, but maybe my bug is somewhere else then

Comment: @Bogey I would suspect the bug is elsewhere.

Comment: Also note that on x86 you don't need further mutual exclusion (in the assembly) - `mov` and friends are already guaranteed to be atomic.

Comment: @MaxLanghof In C++ you still need `std::atomic` so that the compiler doesn't optimize the load out of the loop. Before `std::atomic` people abused `volatile` for that.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin That's why I added "in the assembly". Of course you can't remove the synchronization in the C++ code. I was just looking to further elaborate on the lack of assembly-level synchronization operations that OP perceived.

Comment: @MaxLanghof You would have to `asm volatile` in that case, and you really don't want to go there. In conclusion, just atomic.

Comment: @Bogey: does `#pragma optimize( "", off )` stop the function from inlining?  That's probably significant, because a non-inline function typically has to be treated as a memory barrier for compile-time reordering.  (Because an unknown function might read/write any data that there might be a global pointer to.)  That might indicate a data race on non-atomic variables in the caller of this that allows something to be optimized away.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: the OP said they thought `memory_order_sequential_cst` would be a *compiler* barrier that prevented compile-time reordering or optimizing away.  Not that they expected to see a *runtime* `mfence` barrier instruction in the asm.  (But yes, atomic seq-cst loads don't need anything stronger than what x86 does all the time for naturally-aligned loads.  But seq-cst stores need to use `xchg`, or `mov`+`mfence` to block StoreLoad reordering.  It's technically possible to do it the other way around, and make loads expensive but stores cheaper.  But nobody wants that.)

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes . I've found my bug now - the #pragma did stop inlining, but it just "prevented" the bug by making the call overall a tiny bit slower, which in turn triggered a slightly different polling strategy I'm using - and the bug was rooted in that alternative fallback polling strategy. So the code above is fine indeed, the issue was in an unrelated part of the code. Thanks for everyone's input!